# Nullable Int Type to be associated with a value within a Loop - What is your favourite approch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, programming-languages

I use C# and ASP.NET.

I use this code pasted below in my application with no problems, but I would like to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result.

What I need to do:

I need set a variable `int imageId` using a Loop.
Variable imageId it is outside the Loop so can be used in other part of my code.

My questions:

- Why if I use just `int imageId;` the compiler complain (ERROR: Use of unassigned local variable 'imageId' )?
- I use a `nullable int type` instead of an `int imageId = 0;` so I can set it on a null value .. (to me seems semantically correct) would you recommend that? If no why.
- What is you favorite approach to this kind of problem?

Thanks guys for your support!!!!

```
           int? imageId = null;
            foreach (DictionaryEntry valueEntry in e.Keys)
            {
                if (valueEntry.Key.Equals("ImageContentId"))
                {
                    imageId = Convert.ToInt32(valueEntry.Value.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Please give me a sample of your code thank!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewdeleteeventargs.aspx

Comment: e come from GridViewDeleteEventArgs

Comment: What does the complier state when you try and convert the 'Nullable<int>' to an 'int'?

Comment: Error 1 Use of unassigned local variable 'imageId'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the IOrderedDictionary method [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.contains.aspx). This would allow you to drop the loop construct altogether. e.g.

```
if( e.Keys.Contains("ImageContentId") )
{
    imageId = Convert.ToInt32( e.Keys["ImageContentId"].ToString() );
}
```

Also if you know that the Value is a string you might be interested in the [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method e.g.

```
int imageId ;
if( Int32.TryParse(e["ImageContentId"].ToString(), out imageId ) )
{ }
```

The only reason that you would want to use an `int?` is if the data you're manipulating could be uninitialised. If you're parsing data and it's garbage you have 2 options:
(NB: This assumes that you don't want to be throwing Exceptions RE the bad data).

1) Use a default value - This has the benefit of being inherently tolerant of bad data.

2) Use the `int?` construct - This has the advantage of informing the rest of the code that the data in known to be bad and ensures that they are designed to cope with null values.

As for which is better... that can only be answered within the constructs of the system. If you're performing interop with external dll's that don't support nullable types then the decision is pretty clear!

As for the compiler error: if you're initializing `imageId` within an `if` statement there will be occasions where the initialization branch won't be taken e.g. a bad value. To ensure that `imageId` is always initialized, the compiler will force you to initialize it outside of a conditional code path. Generally I always try and initialize a variable when I declare it.  e.g.

```
int imageId = 0;
```

Comment: Please could you refer to my questions posted? THanks

Comment: For IOrderedDictionary, you can just use Contains http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionary.contains.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Answers for your Questions

- All value type in .net are implemented as structure. And all structure must be initialized before usage.
- If you are interested in checking if that value exists or not then nullable is a correct choice. Else no issues with `int imageId = 0`
- You can use below code

```
 int imageId = 0;
 if( e.Contains("ImageContentId") )
 {
     //If you are sure value is int
     imageId = (int)e["ImageContentId"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Linq to find the entry:

```
var foundKey = e.Keys.FirstOrDefault(k => k.Key.Equals('ImageContentId'));
```

Then the ternary expression to get the value:

```
int? imageId = foundKey == null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(foundKey.Value);
```

However, what type is the Value? If you're sure it's an `int`, you can cast it, rather than calling `Convert.ToInt32`. Also, `Convert.ToInt32` returns 0 for some cases where you might want `(int?)null`.

Answer (score 0):

My favorite approach to this kind of problem is not to rely on overloading the value-holding variable with information regarding whether a value was found. I do this explicitly.

```
bool value_present = false;
int imageId;

foreach (DictionaryEntry valueEntry in e.Keys)
{
    if (valueEntry.Key.Equals("ImageContentId"))
    {
        value_present = true;
        imageId = Convert.ToInt32(valueEntry.Value.ToString());
        break;
    }
}
```

And then test `value_present` before using `imageId`.

That said, and as others have noted, this is crazy.

- Don't loop like this, just call `e.Keys.Contains()`
- Don't convert to a string and then back to an int. If it's an int, cast it.